# Plotting dashed line

Tags: plot, line, gnuplot

How to plot a `dashed` grey line using gnuplot? `set style line 1 lt 2 lc rgb "grey" lw 1`

I tried:

```
plot "-" using 1:2, \
     "-" using 1:2, \
     "-" using 1:2 ls 1,\
     "-" using 1:2 ls 1
1.5 17
1.7 16
e
1.5 10
1.7 8
e
1.5 0
1.5 20
e
7 0
7 20
e
```

There should be two vertical dashed grey lines, but there are actually only the points.

Comment: The command `test` is a nice way to see exactly how your current terminal is behaving.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have the plot command default to `with lines`, you need `set style data lines`. You have to specify `termoption dashed` to get dashed lines, but that also means that `linetype 2` and up are dashed or dotted. I think defining the appropriate line styles is the best approach:

```
set termoption dashed

set style data lines
set style line 1 lt 2 lc rgb "grey" lw 1
set style line 2 lt 1 lc 1 lw 1
set style line 3 lt 1 lc 2 lw 1

plot "-" using 1:2 ls 2, \
     "-" using 1:2 ls 3, \
     "-" using 1:2 ls 1, \
     "-" using 1:2 ls 1
1.5 17
1.7 16
e
1.5 10
1.7 8
e
1.5 0
1.5 20
e
7 0
7 20
e
```

Comment: Another issue was, that dashed lines don't work with the `png` backend. I had to change to `set terminal pngcairo`